# <jsp:include> not respecting position styles of the jsp included

Tags: java, css, jsp, css-position, jspinclude

I have an `index.jsp` which includes `header.jsp` by `<jsp:include>`. The doc `header.jsp` has 2 elements that I've positioned at the **bottom right corner**. If I execute the `header` file as .html, both elements are positioned correctly, but when I execute `index.jsp` both items are at the **top right corner** ignoring **just** the position style because, as you can see, the `loginButton` and `messageLabel` divs still have the rest of their styles.

This is what I see if I execute the `header` like an html (I see it properly):
[image]

And this is what I see if I execute the `index.jsp` in my local server:
[image]

The `index.jsp`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `header.jsp`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Resources/Styles/headerStyles.css" />
<header id="header">
    <label id="messageLabel">User not registered</label>
    <div id="loginButton">
        Login
    </div>
</header>
```

The `headerStyles.css`:

```
#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92px;
}

#loginButton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8;
    top: 60;
    background-color: darkorange;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

#messageLabel {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100;
    top: 70;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it. You only have to specify the unit of measurement in attributes `right` and `top` like this:

```
#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92px;
}

#loginButton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 60px;
    background-color: darkorange;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

#messageLabel {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 70px;
}
```

It seems measures must be followed by their proper unit of measurement correctly specified. It's quite strict.